# Functor of points of a tensor triangulated category

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, stable-homotopy, triangulated-categories

Is there is a functor of points approach to tensor triangulated categories parallel to Balmer's theory of prime spectra?

Given a tensor triangulated category $\mathcal{T}$ an $R$-point can be possibly thought about as a tensor triangulated functor $\mathcal{T} \to D^b(R)$.

What can be said about the faithfulness of the functor $$\otimes\Delta Cat \to PSh_{Sets}(CRings)$$ sending a $\mathcal{T}$ to the presheaf sending $R$ to the set of $R$-points of $\mathcal{T}$?

Can this point of view be used to talk about points of the stable homotopy category, similar to the classification of its thick prime ideals by Devinatz, Hopkins, Smith?

Comment: I doubt that that functor is fully faithful (since for example I don't expect the stable homotopy category to have enough points in an ordinary ring) but I don't know how to make it precise

Comment: Also, my intuition says that the tensor triangulated functors should be considered as a groupoid and not a set if you want to get a reasonable theory